# Safe exception not commit db transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have created an business exception class extends from Exception class and marked this class as @ApplicationException(rollback = false)

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = false)
public abstract class safeValidationException extends Exception{
   ....
}
```

Then when i do the following :

```
try{ 
    functionThrowsafeValidationException () 
}catch(safeValidationException e){
    dao.updatePerson(p);
}


@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PersonDAO implements IPersonDAO {

    private EntityManager emEntityManager;

     public Person updatePerson (final Person p) {
        Person  merged = emEntityManager.merge(p);
        emEntityManager.flush();
        return merged;
    }
```

In step A, am calling a function that update a db field, The query printed in the console but nothing updated in the database.

What is the wrong of my code ?

P.S.: am using EJB , Hibernate

Comment: Not enough info here about the sql statement and how its being executed and committed. Can you elaborate? If you are expecting data in the database, I'm assuming then an exception doesn't occur and the issue is not with the exception but the sql.  I'd look for any rollback points created, where the data transaction is committed and the rollback removed.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay, I have updated the answer with more details. Actually the issue not in the sql in the debug mode i entered the catch and then go to the DAO and when the flush statement is executed the update statement printed at the log

Comment: Shouldn't the dao.updatePerson(p) be in the try block, not the catch block?  If the exception is thrown when its not safe, the update will only occur then.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay, I need to do the update if the function in the try return safeValidationException which at the end business exception

Comment: And the exception cached in the catch block is safe as i marked it  @ApplicationException(rollback = false)

Comment: The call to flush creates the statement you see in your console, but are you sure that a transaction-commit follows? What happens if you annotate the dao method with TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW? I think in that case the change will be seen in the dbms.

Comment: I am getting the following exception if marked TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW : " Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): "

Comment: But the values updated in the db but the exception is thrown? Am not sure why it is trying to update it twice n the same session, Do u have any idea ?

Comment: How you can create instance of your exception because it's **abstract** class?